# Creating separate layers out of one big polygon shape by using attributes

Tags: qgis, vector

I have a big polygon shape (> 200 fields). I have the owners of these fields in a column. I need the separated shapes for each owner. Is there a tool to do that?

Is it also possible to get an information about the whole area? Like a summary:

- 201 polygons
- Area: 1450 ha

In Saga I have a tool "Split shapes by attribute". This works fine with the expected result (10 owners: 10 new layers). This tool doesn't work with the Sextante plugin.

Comment: anything on this tutorial help... http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-styling-vector-data-in-qgis.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split Vector Layer tool in Vector menu should do the job of creating separate Shapefiles based on one field but it seems broken in QGIS 1.8. Try experimental **Shapefile Splitter** plugin which Jake suggested instead.

The number of polygons in a layer is listed in Layer Properties - **Metadata** tab:  "number of features in this layer: x"

With the **Statist** plugin you also get counts and sums (and unique values and much more) for values in a field of your choice. Set it to the area field, and you'll get the area sum for the layer. (You can calculate area using field calculator if it's not available in the attribute table yet.)

Another alternative might be **[GroupStats](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GroupStats/)** plugin.

Comment: I tried using the Split Vector Layer tool, but it didn't work for me (QGIS hangs without error message). The experimental Shapefile Splitter plugin works flawlessly, though.

Comment: Good to know that there is an alternative. I've used the Split Vector Layer tool successfully before.

Comment: I have tried the Split vector layer tool. The problem is, that I got just one polygon shape. I expected separeted shapes for each owner. I had to define a name of the result shape. But I have 10 different owners. In Saga I have a tool "Split shapes by attribute". This works fine with the expected result (10 owners: 10 new layers). This tool doesnt work with the sextante plugin.

Comment: The Split Vector layer tool expects a directory to be selected where it should write the files to. The name of the shapefiles will be created from the attribute table field you selected. I got it working with a shapefile layer, but not with a spatialite layer.

Answer (score 4):

The SAGA algorithm has been removed and there is a native one implemented as an example script in SEXTANTE. It is called "Split vector layer by attribute".

Comment: The resulting files are named, appending a number. You you edit the script and edit the following line: `outputFile = output + "_" + str(len(writers)) + ".shp"` to suit your needs in case you want a differnt naming